# How to make apps update automatically when the screen is off in Google Play store?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

My problem is that my device is not updating apps when I hit the auto-update button; it does only update all apps if the screen is on all the time! How do I make them update when the screen is off?  I mean is that new in the higher version of Play store, what is that functionality? Is this just me or all the other devices that have an updated version of Play store?

Comment: Simple case - when your screen sleeps, does your network connection, too? Does your Wifi disconnect during sleep?

Comment: No it does not ! this happens on all devices that I have, not just this one

Comment: Power Saving Mode, or some battery savers, maybe? BTW - My tablet has an advanced Wifi setting - "Keep Wif-Fi on during sleep"; you may have to search for it. Mine is in Wifi\Advanced, and I have it enabled.

Comment: Still the same, thx btw :)

Comment: One last guess - Do you have an automation app, like Tasker, or Llama, running that engages something like a "sleep" profile, which turns things off? Then a "wake" profile to return them in the morning?

Comment: Well no cause my phone is still fresh no apps are installed, my device is Xperia Sp btw , so is this a playstore build in thing ?

Comment: I don't think so. Thanks for identifying your device. Google "xperia sp wifi sleep" yields a web page on point. It seems to support the theme of my comments, and specifically my second guess.

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site after posting the question, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the **settings** option in the play store and switch on the **Auto-update apps over Wi-Fi only**. :)

Comment: How does this address the screen sleep issue?  Especially when Wi-Fi sleeping seems to be the cause?

Comment: He will have to disable background data restriction, maybe.